# How to Offer Review Services

Tags: publications

A booknote of mine was just accepted for publication. I've been in contact with the editor throughout the process, and want write an email thanking him, and also indicating that I'd be happy to be considered as a potential reviewer in the future. What would be an appropriate way to phrase this email?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Dear Editor,
>
> Thank you for accepting my booknote for publication. I'd be happy to be considered as a potential reviewer for your publication in the future.
>
> Best wishes,
>
> user82138"

Perhaps this is facetious, but as far as I know there's no special code that needs to be invoked when communicating with journal editors. Concise, plain English will certainly suffice.

Comment: As a journal editor, I agree. The only thing you might add is an indication of areas of interest and specialization, and/or a CV.